# Can I load a Kohana class in the file that placed in a root directory?

Tags: kohana-3.3

I'm trying to use Kohana class in my install.php file that placed right in the root directory, but when I'm trying to use it I see this:

**install.php**

```
require_once ("system/classes/Kohana.php");

$kohana = new Kohana();

// out: Fatal error: Class 'Kohana_Core' not found in \system\classes\Kohana.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you're using this file for anything? The file install.php must be renamed or deleted after you have verified that you have got Kohana set up as it should be.

I don't know if that's what is causing the particular error, but you still should avoid using install.php for anything. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move any files from the normal Kohana structure after download? Is the install.php file in the same location as the /system/ folder of your Kohana version or you mean that your install.php is outside the Kohana root?

What do you intend to do with the install.php? Are you adding your own code for different checks?